# Let's get critical: Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Biology Stack Exchange](http://biology.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://biology.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is there a biological mechanism for evolution encoded into our DNA?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/is-there-a-biological-mechanism-for-evolution-encoded-into-our-dna)

**Net Score: 26** (Excellent: 27, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the mechanism of oxygen uptake in E. coli?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20632/what-is-the-mechanism-of-oxygen-uptake-in-e-coli)

**Net Score: 23** (Excellent: 24, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is this vinca like vine?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20994/what-is-this-vinca-like-vine)

**Net Score: 17** (Excellent: 18, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Spider identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20479/help-me-identify-this-spider)

**Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 17, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Importance of knowing GC Content of an organism](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21113/importance-of-knowing-gc-content-of-an-organism)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Why has grey hair evolved?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20709/why-has-grey-hair-evolved)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 17, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Regarding the difference between cDNA library and RNA sequencing (Biochem. technique)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20697/regarding-the-difference-between-cdna-library-and-rna-sequencing-biochem-techn)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [What is the functional significance of the difference in cardiolipin/cholesterol ratio in different membranes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20559/what-is-the-functional-significance-of-the-difference-in-cardiolipin-cholesterol)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

- [Can a single axon propagate multiple simultaneous action potentials?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21137/can-a-single-axon-propagate-multiple-simultaneous-action-potentials)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 16, Needs Improvement: 8)

---

- [How to estimate the DNA density in human sperm head?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/how-to-estimate-the-dna-density-in-human-sperm-head)

**Net Score: -12** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 15)

---

Answer (score 2):

I had a doubt regarding this. During self evaluation I noticed that some of the posts could be improved (In fact I answered a couple of them in this process). Is it right to do so as it may cause discordance in evaluation (between pre- and post- edit evaluations) ?

Comment: I also thought that the selection of posts was unfortunate.

Comment: @fileunderwater Definitely, it was an exceedingly poor sampling.

Comment: I don't see any problems here, any more than editing/answering normally.

Comment: You guys definitely had a lot more participation than [we did over on GL](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/588/lets-get-critical-oct-2014-site-self-evaluation). But we got more than before, and I happened to answer 7, and ask 1, out of the ten there. :P